# How to skip or delete rows from the excel file using apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am working with an excel file which i have to convert to a text file and i have to choose specific rows from that.I have done already but i am stuc with the end of the file bacause i have to delete or skip 3 rows there and their position might change dynamially.So i am sharing the screen of the excel file 
[image]

Three hightlighted rows i have to skip or delete and their position might change dynamically.I am giving the code which i have used to get specific rows from the file

```
@Override
public List < String > processSheet(Sheet sheet) {
    ActivityLauncher.logConsoleMsg("Processing sheet " + sheet.getSheetName() + " started");
    List < String > rows = new ArrayList < String > ();
    Iterator < Row > rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        Row currentRow = rowIterator.next();
        StringBuilder row = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < currentRow.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
            if (currentRow.getRowNum() == 0 || currentRow.getRowNum() == 1 || 
                    currentRow.getRowNum() == 2 || currentRow.getRowNum() == 3 || 
                    currentRow.getRowNum() == 4 || currentRow.getRowNum() == 5 || 
                    currentRow.getRowNum() == 6 || currentRow.getRowNum() == 7 || 
                    currentRow.getRowNum() == 9 || currentRow.getRowNum() == 10 || 
                    currentRow.getRowNum() == 11) {
                continue;
            } else {
                Cell currentCell = currentRow.getCell(i, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
                String cellValue = excelManager.evalCell(currentCell);

                if (cellValue.contains("Total")) { //i have tried here
                    continue;
                }
                if (!cellValue.isEmpty()) {
                    row.append(cellValue);
                }

                //adjusting the cell values with the | or BLANK 
                if (currentCell == null || currentCell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
                    row.append("");
                } else {
                    row.append(SEPARATOR);
                }
            }
        }
        if (!row.toString().isEmpty()) {
            rows.add(row.toString());
        }
    }
    ActivityLauncher.logConsoleMsg("Processing sheet " + sheet.getSheetName() + " completed");
    return rows;
}
```

I can not skip by position because the position might change by time.

Comment: You could check value in the cell in the first column in screenshot. If it is empty or contains `Total` then skip that row.

Comment: @Ivan can you modify my code please ? i really not getting any idea

Comment: @Ivan see i  have made some try but still it is not getting in  prope way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that column with values `ARC...` is the first column. If not then please change value for `startCell` variable to correct value.

```
@Override
public List < String > processSheet(Sheet sheet) {
    ActivityLauncher.logConsoleMsg("Processing sheet " + sheet.getSheetName() + " started");
    List <String> rows = new ArrayList<String>();
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
    final int startCell = 0;
    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
        Row currentRow = rowIterator.next();
        StringBuilder row = new StringBuilder();
        // not sure if you really need this if statement in your Prod code
        if (currentRow.getRowNum() == 0 || currentRow.getRowNum() == 1 || 
                currentRow.getRowNum() == 2 || currentRow.getRowNum() == 3 || 
                currentRow.getRowNum() == 4 || currentRow.getRowNum() == 5 || 
                currentRow.getRowNum() == 6 || currentRow.getRowNum() == 7 || 
                currentRow.getRowNum() == 9 || currentRow.getRowNum() == 10 || 
                currentRow.getRowNum() == 11) {
            continue;
        } 
        if (currentRow.getLastCellNum() < 0 || currentRow.getCell(startCell) == null || "".equals(currentRow.getCell(startCell).getStringValue()) || (currentRow.getCell(startCell).getStringValue() != null && currentRow.getCell(startCell).getStringValue().contains("Total"))) {
            continue;
       }
       for (int i = 0; i < currentRow.getLastCellNum(); i++) {
         else {
            Cell currentCell = currentRow.getCell(i, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
            String cellValue = excelManager.evalCell(currentCell);
            if (!cellValue.isEmpty()) {
                row.append(cellValue);
            }

            //adjusting the cell values with the | or BLANK 
            if (currentCell == null || currentCell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
                row.append("");
            } else {
                row.append(SEPARATOR);
            }
        }
    }
    if (!row.toString().isEmpty()) {
        rows.add(row.toString());
    }
  }
  ActivityLauncher.logConsoleMsg("Processing sheet " + sheet.getSheetName() + " completed");
  return rows;
}
```

Comment: can i use your solution in wiping out a column also ?